# NERDTree changes my visual indention

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I installed NERDTree for vim. But now it changes my visual indention in each line where this rectangle occures in the navigation bar.
I talk about visual indention because it does not change my actual indention but it just seems like.
It wouldn't be that bad, but indention is important in python, so it is really annoying.
Any suggestions what the cause could be?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQIJ4.png)

Answer (score 1):

NERDTree is using some Unicode arrow glyphs for open/closed directories, and it looks like your font doesn't have them. You can override the glyphs with something like this in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
let g:NERDTreeDirArrowExpandable = '+'
let g:NERDTreeDirArrowCollapsible = '-'
```

Or disable the arrows with:

```
let g:NERDTreeDirArrows = 0
```

If you think your font has glyphs, but they're not being used, try adding this to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
scriptencoding utf-8
set encoding=utf-8
```

If the encoding fixes things, there's likely a problem with your terminal type, and it'd be better to fix that instead (possibly the wrong `TERM` environment variable, or Vim's `term` option is wrong, although unless you explicitly set it, it should be the same as `TERM`).

The default arrow glyphs that it uses are `▸` and `▾`.

Comment: This is an old post, but I found it while looking for a way to use unicode characters directly in my config, and found that you can do something like this as well:

`let NERDTreeDirArrowExpandable = "\u25B7"` and `let NERDTreeDirArrowCollapsible = "\u25bC"`